# Homeomorphism between $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: 1<\|x\|<2\}$ and $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: \|x\|>1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: 1<\|x\|<2\}$ homeomorphic to $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: \|x\|>1\}$ ?

Comment: Define $f(x)=\frac{x}{(2-||x||)||x||}$

Comment: @Spark : how would someone guess that map.. could you please explain a bit more...

Answer (score 3):

HINT: You just need to find a map that stretches the open annulus radially. Find a homeomorphism $h:(1,2)\to(1,\infty)$, and use the map $\langle r,\theta\rangle\mapsto\langle h(r),\theta\rangle$, where I’ve represented points in the plane by their polar coordinates. To find a suitable $h$, consider the behavior of $\frac1{2-x}$ for $x\in(1,2)$.

Comment: Sir, I am really excited by seeing this idea :)  I could now see that $h$ defined as $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{2-x}$ is a homeomorphism and so is the map $(x,y)\rightarrow (h(x),y)$ as first projection is homeomorphism as checked and second component map is constant map so is homeomorphism.. Could you please tell me if what i am seeing sufficient or am i missing something?

Comment: @Praphulla: You’re not missing anything: that’s exactly the idea that I had in mind.